# Get users list of Office 365 account through api

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, office365api

I have setup an Office 365 business account.How can I access the list of users I have added in my account via API?

Here is the screenshot of my account and users list which I need to fetch- https://www.screencast.com/t/Bq1M3qegUQt.

Actually I need to get this user list along with each user's role(Global administrator,User(no admin access) likewise).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Office 365 API functionality is also available through the [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview)(recommend), a unified API that includes APIs from other Microsoft service .

With Microsoft Graph api , you could [list users](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list) via:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

You could use [List memberOf](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_memberof) to get groups and directory roles that the user is a direct member of :

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/memberOf
```

Below is the result for your reference:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole",
            "id": "bee946b1-bf9c-4d97-bdb6-41931e37e677",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "description": "Company Administrator role has full access to perform any operation in the company scope.",
            "displayName": "Company Administrator",
            "roleTemplateId": "62e90394-69f5-4237-9190-012177145e10"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
            "id": "e1b32e43-dab2-49e1-a2f3-51e391888a44",
            "deletedDateTime": null,
            "classification": null,
            "createdDateTime": "2017-04-06T08:15:54Z",
            "description": "MySite",
            "displayName": "MySite",
            "groupTypes": [
                "Unified"
            ],
            "mail": "MySite@chencl.onmicrosoft.com",
            "mailEnabled": true,
            "mailNickname": "MySite",
            "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
            "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
            "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
            "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
            "proxyAddresses": [
                "SMTP:MySite@chencl.onmicrosoft.com"
            ],
            "renewedDateTime": "2017-04-06T08:15:54Z",
            "securityEnabled": false,
            "visibility": "Public"
        }
    ]
}
```

You could get [the roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles) by filtering the results which `@odata.type` is `#microsoft.graph.directoryRole` . You could check the administrator roles [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-assign-admin-roles) . If user has no admin access(User) , there is no `directoryRole` values with above rest api . For how to get access tokens to call Microsoft Graph , you could click [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview) for more details.